# Ubuntu can't find the PICKIT3 driver

Tags: hardware, pic

I am kind of a beginner in ubuntu. I've installed MPLAB X v3.65 but can't find the PICKIT3 driver.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGtas.png)

Does anybody know a way to program PIC with PICkIT3 on ubuntu? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks it could be an issue with USB driver permissions in ubuntu.  The driver itself should come with MPLAB X.

See:
http://en.microstickplus.com/mplabx-on-linux

Might be describing what you are seeing.